# TypeScript: Correct type when passing an html image as an argument instead of any

Tags: typescript

I'm using `any`, but my linter is complaining, I'm passing an image

```
  const canvasControl = (image: any) => {
  console.log(image)
  };
```

the console log out
`<img src="blob:http://localhost:3000/25d85923-afc9-4a57-839c-539bf1a22c60">`

Comment: It's seems more like a ```string``` or ```HTMLElement``` type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should type it as `HTMLImageElement`.